# Will Flash Exe files still work after Flash support is finally dropped

Tags: windows, flash

If Flash is dead in 2020, will Flash EXE files still work? My opinion is yes because, the player is right included into the EXE. Am I right or is there something I missed out? Is it expected to still work in newer windows versions?

Answer (score 2):

> *"If Flash is dead in 2020, will Flash EXE files still work?"*

Yes. It's the browser **plugin** that is stopping in 2020.

When Flash CS or Animate CC software is used to output an EXE from compiled AS3 code, that EXE has everything built-in it needs to play the Flash content. Think of it as standalone player.